# How filter a table based on two different filters?

Tags: powerbi

Talk guys, all quiet? I have a case where I need to filter a table based on two different filters, example:I need to return within a word cloud two combinations of the same table.I have a table that contains the data of Title, id, words, qtd.

I currently have a table that contains, for example:

| table | Title | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orientacao | Text1 | 1 |
| Projeto | Text2 | 2 |
| Artigos | Text3 | 3 |

Basically what I need is to be able to filter this table with two filters:

```
filter 1 -> "table options"
filter 2 -> "table options"
```

Both filters will have the same data, but the end result should be to filter the word cloud from these two filters.

Example:

```
filter 1 -> Orientacao
filter 2 -> Artigos
```

Result:

| Title |
| --- |
| Text1 |
| Text2 |

But in the tests I did when I make the two selections, the word cloud is blank, I can't make these two selections.

Is it clearer?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Please post sample data and desired output.

Comment: @David, Is it clearer, now?

Comment: Should the result say Text1 and Text3? 

Are you looking for a combination of slicers to perform "OR" functionality rather than the default "AND" functionality. So instead of rows matching Orientacao AND Artigos which intersects to nothing you want Orientacao OR Artigos?